# Why do my files only appear when the drive is unmounted?

Tags: arch-linux, fstab, automounting, non-root-user

## Background

I'd like to store music on `/dev/sda1`, which is a physically separate drive. The `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
# grep "music" /etc/fstab
UUID=10...92 /mnt/music ext4 defaults,user,rw 0 2
```

## Problem

When the system restarts, the files disappear:

```
# ls /mnt/music/
lost+found
```

When unmounting the drive, the files reappear:

```
# umount /mnt/music
# ls /mnt/music
archives  jazz  logs  scripts
```

In both cases, the directory `/mnt/music` is owned by the user account, not the root account.

I've also tried changing the `/etc/fstab` entry to:

```
UUID=10...92 /mnt/music ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user=USERNAME 0 2
```

## Question

How do you mount a drive in Arch Linux such that it is read-write for a specific user at startup (without having to unmount the drive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrote the files to the wrong filesystem (the one containing the `/mnt/music` directory, rather than the on on `/dev/sda1`).

To fix this, get the admin to move the mount elsewhere, and move the files from `/mnt/music` into the mounted filesystem.

| user-only version |
| --- |
| Alternatively, as an ordinary user, umount the filesystem and cd into `/mnt/music`. |
| Then mount the filesystem. Now, `/mnt/music` is your filesystem and `.` is the underlying (shadowed) directory - confirm that, e.g. using `ls`. |
| Now put the files where you wanted them: `mv * /mnt/music`. |

`sync` for good luck, and you're done.

To ensure that the filesystem gets mounted at boot time, get `auto` added to its mount options in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: IMHO it's less obsecure to just mount the desired target filesystem on somewhere else (e.g. /tmp/mnt) temporarily. (To be frank, I had a hard time figuring out what you were suggesting. Maybe it's just me though.)

Comment: Yes, if you are `root` when doing that.  But if you're mounting and umounting as user, you can't choose a different mountpoint.

Comment: True. Still since the OP mentioned changing fstab, I'm quite sure he isn't under that kind of "limited" circumstances.

Comment: I still wouldn't advocate doing the copy as root - call me old-fashioned, but I'm a strong advocate of using the minimum necessary privilege.  I'll see if I can re-word for the case when the admin is willing to change the mountpoint.

Comment: @DaveJarvis - I've rejected your edit suggestion that adds a different method.  You should create an answer of your own rather than hijacking an existing one.

Comment: `I still wouldn't advocate doing the copy as root` For the record, neither do I. There's no relation at all between who you (re-)mount as and who you copy/move files as. (With that said, I don't advocate "avoid root" here either, because in this case, it's really about the ownership/permission of the two filesystems and the files. It's not like the case of starting an X server or so.)